# FFMPEG: concat demuxer errors during execution

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the FFMPEG concat demuxer to create a "loop" of a single video.

I first tried running this command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i behzad.txt -c:v copy output_concat.avi
```

My input text file is as follows:

```
file 'G:\Masters_Thesis_Files\Honda_Database\Database1\Training\videos\behzad\behzad.avi'
file 'G:\Masters_Thesis_Files\Honda_Database\Database1\Training\videos\behzad\behzad.avi'
```

The input file is in raw format.

After running the command I get the following output to the console and the video generated is just the first frame of my input video file.

```
ffmpeg version N-74286-ge5774f2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --
enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-l
ibilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enab
le-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --en
able-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --ena
ble-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc
 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enabl
e-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --ena
ble-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 30.100 / 54. 30.100
  libavcodec     56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 32.100 /  5. 32.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, concat, from 'behzad.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000001, bitrate: 110806 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 640x480, 110806 kb/s, 14.99 fps, 14.99
tbr, 14.99 tbn, 14.99 tbc
File 'output_concat.avi' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, avi, to 'output_concat.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 640x480, q=2-31, 110806 kb/s, 14.99 fps
, 14.99 tbr, 14.99 tbn, 14.99 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[avi @ 0000000004723360] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 1186
24821151886176, current: 118624821151886176; changing to 118624821151886177. Thi
s may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0000000004723360] Too large number of skipped frames 118624821151886176 >
 60000
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
[avi @ 0000000004723360] Too large number of skipped frames 118624821151886176 >
 60000
frame=    2 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=     906kB time=-00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A
video:1800kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing
overhead: unknown
Conversion failed!
```

I also tried to run the command with the codec set to h264, rather than just copying the codec. When I ran this command the output to the console still had the DTS errors, however, my output video contained the entire input video rather than just the first frame.  It did not repeat the video like I expect.

I should also specify, I'm running these commands in Windows using the latest version of Zeranoe FFMPEG.

I'm still relatively inexperienced with FFMPEG, is there some part of the process that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show the **complete** console output from your command and not just a segment. Info from the input will be helpful too: `ffmpeg -i behzad.avi`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question to show the full console output.  As for the video information, I'm not sure what information would be helpful in addition to the information given in the console output. Looking at the file information in VLC the codec is shown as 24 bits RGB (RV24), the resolution is 640x480, and the frame rate is 14.99 fps. Is there a way to get more information about the file?